# Underscore multidimensional sortBy

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js

I have an object.

```
[
    { "home1": { "mesafe":11 } },
    { "home2": { "mesafe": 6 } },
    { "home3": { "mesafe":42 } },
    { "home4": { "mesafe":23 } },
    { "home5": { "mesafe": 5 } }
]
```

How can I sort this object with `mesafe` field order by ASC numeric using underscore ?

Comment: See the [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider

```
{
  "home1": {
    "mesafe":11 
  }
}
```

as

```
{
  "home1": {
    "mesafe":11 
  }, 
  // fakes
  "home2": {},  
  "home3": {}...
}
```

Now the value to sort can be described to :

Get all `mesafe` attribute's value from subObject  and sum them up (if the attribute exist).

So you can use `_.reduce` to achieve it.

```js
var list = [
    { "home1": { "mesafe":11 } },
    { "home2": { "mesafe": 6 } },
    { "home3": { "mesafe":42 } },
    { "home4": { "mesafe":23 } },
    { "home5": { "mesafe": 5 } }
];

var sortedList = _.sortBy(list, function(item) {
  
  // For each item, we acts as  there not only have one attribute "homex", but there's many other like "homey : {}".
  var res =  _.reduce(item, function(res, sub) {
    // So we can the again use reduce to iterate through them, and add the value if mesafe exist.
    return (sub.mesafe == null) ? res : res + sub.mesafe;
  }, 0);
  
  return res;
});

console.log(sortedList);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JavaScript Array sort() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) to sort the array based on value in `mesafe` field.

```js
var data = [
    { "home1": { "mesafe":11 } },
    { "home2": { "mesafe": 6 } },
    { "home3": { "mesafe":42 } },
    { "home4": { "mesafe":23 } },
    { "home5": { "mesafe": 5 } }
];

// get the value from mesafe field
function getMesafeValue(a) {
  for (var key in a) {
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      return a[key].mesafe;
    }
  }
}

// sort the array
data.sort(function(a, b) {

  var v1 = getMesafeValue(a);
  var v2 = getMesafeValue(b);

  return v1 < v2 ? -1 : (v1 > v2 ? 1 : 0);
});

// print the array after sorting
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (var key in data[i]) {
    if (data[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      document.write(key + " -> " + data[i][key].mesafe + '<br/>');
    }
  }
}
```